# Armature doesn't work properly

Tags: animation, rigging, armature

I have rigged a left foot in Blender and want to rig the other foot, but when I test the another foot, the armature didn't work well.

The armature twitches or flickers as shown in this video.

[Video Showing Issue](https://youtu.be/fBhVBLvFJXM)

[image]

Comment: could you share your armature? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=6042" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/6042/)

Comment: That's it, this happens when I put an IK on right foot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the linked file there is no right leg bones so it's hard to say what's your problem. Anyway, you can easily fix it:

- First give all your left leg bones a ".L" or "_L" suffix.
- Then select all the left leg bones, go in the *Armature* menu and choose *Symmetrize*.
- You now have right leg bones and they work.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First select the bones. Ctrl+a: Apply transformations. Then do the symetrize.